# c# DateTime need to show only Time

Tags: c#, datetime

There is a field defined in the SQL Server DB as DateTime.
I need to show only the time - 5 PM . Is  it possible through C# to have it show only the Time so that it can go in the DB properly. If so, how do you display the time in C# as 5 PM?

Comment: I answered the 5pm part, but I'm a bit confused about your line *have it show only the Time so that it can go in the DB properly.* You'd still need to pass in a full datetime to sql server. I don't think it would accept 5pm as an input for that field type.

Comment: Down voted due to lack of research before posting. How hard is it to type "DateTime formatting c#" into google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()` is probably the closest you're gonna do without a custom format string.  The output looks like

```
8:54 AM
```

So, it doesn't matter how you store it in the database.  `ToShortTimeString()` will only display the time.

Comment: I think OP is looking to exclude minutes, based on the example.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was the case; that's why I mentioned a custom format string like others have given examples of.

Answer (score 4):

This will do the job

```
DateTime date= new DateTime(2008, 4, 1, 18, 53, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("h tt"));  // Displays 6 PM
```

Comment: Ivan, how do I get it so that it shows today's date but the time is always 5 PM?

Comment: @Nate - You need to be more specific.  *Where* are you trying to show the date and time?  On a label on a form?  On a web page?  In the console?

Answer (score 4):

With [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

```
DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
Time.ToString("h tt");
```

Comment: @JamesJohnson Indeed. Fixed. Thx.